# R independence test between sample of different size

Tags: r, statistics

In statistics, in order to perform a z-test for the difference in means of two samples I have to check for their independence. I have tried with Pearson' Chi Squared test, but it requires that my samples have the same dimension (eg., one is 359 elements long and the other just 141). Is there any other way of doing it?
Here is a sample of my code and my results (each sample is just a vector of numbers):

```
> head(data_feri)
[1] 2.56495 4.26268 3.17805 2.99573 2.30259 0.69315

> head(data_fest)
[1] 3.68888 2.19722 1.60944 3.52636 2.63906 2.48491

> length(data_feri)
[1] 359

> length(data_fest)
[1] 141

> chisq.test(data_fest, data_feri)
Error in chisq.test(data_fest, data_feri) : 
'x' and 'y' must have the same length

> chisq.test(table(data_fest, data_feri))
Error in table(data_fest, data_feri) : 
all arguments must have the same length
```

Comment: This is not appropriate use of a chi-squared test. You should know from the design of your experiment if the two variables are independent.

Comment: Data are about concentration of PM10 near Oslo, and the two samples collects concentration in holidays and in workdays respectively. I am not totally sure I can assume them independent, since in scientific literature they said that concentration can vary very quickly, but it seems strange that concentration on Friday doesn't affect the value on Saturday. I'm trying to check if there's a significative difference between them.

Comment: So, you have time series data and know it is not independent.

Comment: @Roland yes, it's a time series, but I don't know if they are independent or not. I've implemented manually the Pearson' independent test based on the contingency table, and it seems to work properly. The two samples seems to be independent. I still don't understand why the R's function chisq.test doesn't work. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are approaching this in the wrong way (and not using the correct test). You need to treat this as a time series, i.e., investigate auto/cross-correlation and such. I strongly advise you to consult a statistician.

Comment: @Roland Ok, I'll do it, thank you for your advice.